# Is there a way to query a specific view in a list using the Sharepoint REST API?

Tags: python, r, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to find a way to target a specific list view on one of our company's Sharepoint on-premise site.  Right now I'm able to pull from the entire list but there are about 20 different views we use for different reporting purposes on the list, most of which is completely irrelevant to what I need the view for.  Right now I'm writing this in R because it's what I'm most familiar with but if it can be done in Python easier I might be able to switch over to that.  Those are about my only two options here.

I have tried this in two different ways so far using the api, both return no list:

```
URL <- "https://xx.xx.xx.com/Rxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xx')/Views('xx')/items"
R <- GET(URL, httr::authenticate("user","pass",type="any"))
get_r <- httr::content(R, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
get_rj <- fromJSON(get_r)
get_rdf <- as.data.frame(get_rj)
```

```
URL <- "https://xx.xx.com/Rxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xx')/RenderListDataAsStream?view=xx
R <- GET(URL, httr::authenticate("user","pass",type="any"))
get_r <- httr::content(R, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
get_rj <- fromJSON(get_r)
get_rdf <- as.data.frame(get_rj)
```

I've also tried pulling the XML from the specific view but it returns the entire list instead of just the view as well:

```
URLXML<- "https://xx.xx.xx.com/Rxx/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE&List={xx}&View={xx}"
rawData <- getURL(URLXML, userpwd = "user:pass")
xmlData <- xmlParse (rawData, options=HUGE, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
dataList <- xmlToList(xmlRoot(xmlData)[["data"]])
dataMatrix <- do.call(rbind,dataList)
finalDataTable <- data.table(dataMatrix)
```

If anyone has any tricks or tips to throw my way I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

From Python you should be able to consume the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client libraries and do something like this:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://<tenant>/sites/<yoursite>");
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("YourListName");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
View view = list.Views.GetByTitle("YourViewName");
context.Load(view);
context.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;

ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```